# How can I send real data in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, multiplayer

I have game Server-side, update logic with 60 FPS and Send data with 10 FPS

```
var PLAYER_LIST = {};

class Player {
    constructor(socket) {
        this.id = Math.random() * 9999;
        this.pressKeyAttack = 0;
        this.socket = socket;
        PLAYER_LIST[this.id] = this;
    }
    setupSocket() {
        this.socket.on("keypress", (data) => {
            if (data.key == 1) this.pressKeyAttack = data.value;
        });
    }
    send() {
        //Simple data
        //Send to this player all data from PLAYER_LIST
        var data = {};
        for (var id in PLAYER_LIST) {
            data[id] = PLAYER_LIST[id].pressKeyAttack;
        }
        this.socket.emit("data", data);
    }
    update() {
        if (this.pressKeyAttack == 1) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}

io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {
    new Player(socket);
});

setInterval(() => {
    //Logic update
    for (var id in PLAYER_LIST) {
        PLAYER_LIST[id].update();
    }
}, 1000 / 60);

setInterval(() => {
    //Send data
    for (var id in PLAYER_LIST) {
        PLAYER_LIST[id].send();
    }
}, 1000 / 10);
```

Example Client-side, when any player press [Space] then all other player will see animation from that Player.

```
var PLAYER_LIST = {}; //all player

for (var id in PLAYER_LIST) {
    if (PLAYER_LIST[id].pressKeyAttack == 1) {
        //run animation
    }
}

socket.on("data", (data) => {
    for (var id in data) {
        PLAYER_LIST[id].pressKeyAttack = data[id];
    }
})

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    // Player.pressKeyAttack = 1
    if (e.keyCode == 32) socket.emit("keypress", { key: 1, value: 1 });
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    // Player.pressKeyAttack = 0
    if (e.keyCode == 32) socket.emit("keypress", { key: 1, value: 0 });
}
```

**My problem:**

Ex: I'm a player in game (called Player_A) and some other players. When Player_A press [Space] down and up so fast, other players can't receive data (pressKeyAttack = 1) from Player_A, because Loop Send Data run 10 FPS (send every 100ms), Player_A.pressKeyAttack equal 1 and back to 0 in 50ms.

Look like:

```
at 0ms: Player_A.pressKeyAttack = 0;

at 20ms: Player_A.pressKeyAttack = 1; //Player press down

at 50ms: Player_A.pressKeyAttack = 0; //Player press up

at 100ms: Loop Data Run - Player_A.pressKeyAttack = 0.
```

In fact it used to be 1. How can I fix this?

Comment: In your server you could `emit` the data when you receive a `keypress` event. Also you could setup batching of about 5-10ms to reduce multiple emits concurrently. To reduce your payload size, you could just emit the data of the changing elements rather than sending every player's position.

Comment: Don't emit with an interval. Emit on event. In other words, don't emit at a fixed rate (10 times per second) which is uselessly resource consuming, but emit the info only when needed, meaning, when a player presses the spacebar. Something like `socket.on("keypress", data => socket.broadcast("Key was pressed : " + data.keyCode ))`